# How to preselect and highlight a cell from a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I've an array where I've position of previously selected cells. 
I'd like to show to the user the cells that were previously selected (at another moment, can be months ago) by highlighting them and selecting them (if I click on one previously selected I'd like that it unselect it) when my popover appears, as I did in :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

I tried different things like :

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0){
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
}
```

Or :

```
let indexPathForFirstRow = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow)?.isSelected = true
```

But nothing worked (Or I couldn't see it...)

Have you any help to bring on this? 
Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is what I do now:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell

    if (swipeDown![2][0] == (settings!.rowSelect) && indexPath.row == 4 && indexPath.section == 4) {
        let indexPathspec = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 4)
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPathspec) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.isSelected = true

        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.37, blue:0.58, alpha:0.7)
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        print("test")
        return cell

    }
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.37, blue:0.58, alpha:0.7)
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
    print(cell.isSelected)
    print("11")
    return cell
}
```

With this in MyCollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
override var isSelected: Bool{
    didSet{
        //super.isSelected = true
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = self.isSelected ? .blue : .green
    } 
}
}
```

The cell is in blue, so it's selected, but I can't unselect it once it's done. 
No problem for the cells I select after the launch, I can select and deselect them without problem.

Comment: check that your cell is selectable

Comment: @ReinierMelian I've been able to select it before, why couldn't I now ? 
Just want to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, use `isSelected` property of `UICollectionViewCell`.

On how isSelected works, refer to: https://medium.com/@p.gpt10/uicollectionviewcell-selection-made-easy-41dae148379d

For initially selecting a `UICollectionViewCell` use,

```
self.contentCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .left)
```

Also, in `didSelectItemAt` method, you don't need to change `isSelected` or call above method. Just refer to the above tutorial and you will get everything you need.

**Edit:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var aCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "aCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
        cell.myLabel.text = "ok"
        cell.isSelected = false
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        if indexPath.row == 5
        {
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .left) //Add this line
            cell.isSelected = true 
        } 
        return cell 
    } 

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
    } 
}

class myCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            if self.isSelected
            {
                super.isSelected = true
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.28, blue:0.45, alpha:1)
            }
            else
            {
                super.isSelected = false
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.37, blue:0.58, alpha:0.7) 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried it too, with things like: let indexPathForFirstRow = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
            collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow)?.isSelected = true   But that's not working either

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: I missed something the first time, looks like it's working, I'll work a bit more on this and let you know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So, It appears that I'm able to select the cell I want programmatically, but I'm not able to deselect it after... That's annoying as I really need that, do you have an idea how to do it ?

Comment: The cell will be automatically deselected when you select another cell.

Comment: I need multiple selection. so I tried `isSelected = false` of course. It looks like nothing happen when I click on the cell, not even a `print()`. I already did `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151608/discussion-between-pgdev-and-hawkydoky).

Comment: Still not. I still can't unselect a cell that have been select at start. Even with dequeue. I update my question with what I do now.

Comment: I don't understand the issue that you are facing. I provided the link to whole code and still you are not getting it

Comment: I know, and it works perfectly for every cell but these I select at the opening of the popover with `cell.isSelected = true` after dequeuing it and before returning it. I can't do nothing with them.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some stuff for you, i hope it will help to you :

declare variables :

```
var selectIndex = 0
var selectIndexSec = 0
```

in viewDidload() :

```
collectionview.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: selectIndex, section: selectIndexSec) , at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

in collectionview delegate :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    if selectIndexSec == (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section
    {
        if selectIndex == (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
        {
            cell.isSelected=true
        }
        else
        {
            cell.isSelected=false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.isSelected=false
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    selectIndex = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    selectIndexSec = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section
    collectionview.reloadData()
}
```